# Recursive methods

Tags: ruby

I have a response from the Flickr API listing the tree of all my collections.

I basically need a recursive method to loop through and add each collection to my DB.

My head is just completely spinning.

This is what I have:

```
  def add_collection(options = {})
    Collection.create!({
        :flickr_id    =>  options['id'],
        :title        =>  options['title'],
        :description  =>  options['description'],
        :primary      =>  options['primary']
      })
  end

  def self.complete_grab
    collections = Flickr.get_collection_tree
    collections.each do |c|
      add_collection({id: c.id, title: c.title, description: c.description, primary: c.primary})
      if c.has_children?
        //
      end
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts? Am I close to solving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Flickr API, but I think the rough structure you're looking for is:

```
def complete_grab
   add_all(Flickr.get_collection_tree)
end

def add_all(collections)
   collections.each do |c|
      add_collection({id: c.id, title: c.title, description: c.description, primary: c.primary})
      add_all(c.children)
   end
end
```

That assumes that each collection has a member called children that contains multiple child collections.

Comment: That's perfect. I need to start trying to think even more simply than I was.

I'm now stuck with the data I'm getting back from Flickr. It's a mix of arrays and hashes inside of each other and it's tricky figuring out where each starts and ends and how to access each one.